# How do I extend this Netbeans JSF2 CRUD example to have a single create and edit form for all entities?

Tags: mysql, database, jsf, crud

I recently discovered this very useful Netbeans tutorial for creating a simple JSF 2 CRUD application http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud.html.  The final product has somewhat limited usability as one is confronted with a myriad of web pages.  I would like an example of how to consolidate the Create and Edit forms (using the same project if possible).  This seems more in keeping with how a person would actually enter such information and would reduce the risk of data entry mistakes.  Why enter a client and their billing address on separate screens?  One should be able to add or remove addresses, if need be, on the client's edit form.  Or if a new client has multiple addresses, enter them all on the client's create form.  The application just seemed incomplete with no further tips on how to improve it.  If one has knows of a useful book that covers this, then I would gladly read that as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize the complexity of my problem and found that I couldn't get what I needed using JSF2 with the information resources available.  Through my searches, I also found that many others were asking about Master-Detail CRUD applications, which I then learned was what I needed, but in slightly different ways and not getting any solid examples.  A problem properly stated is half solved and I didn't know the problem statement. Armed with more knowledge, I was shocked to find that the answers were not readily available outside of some videos on YouTube showcasing Oracle ADF.  In the end, I was able to quickly build the application I desired using the Play! Framework.  In a way, by not having my question answered I was able to find a solution that would prove to be a better fit for my needs;  though I would have gladly bought a cookbook if someone had pointed one out.

Comment: Are you using POJOS wiht Play with JavaEE? What is the version of Play? I think Play did not get much attention as it deserves.

Comment: Are your not able to generate a single CRUD xhtml page from Netbeas with JSF2? Didn't you find some thing in edburns forum or java.net forums?